# Handling Pagination with Redux and Material UI

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui

Im getting some problems with finishing the pagination on my table.

This is my table:

```
<Table>
    <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Username</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Log level</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Date</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Message</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Details</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
    </TableHead>

    <TableBody>
        { this.props.logs.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage).map((el,ix) => (
        <TableRow key={ix}>
            <TableCell>{el.username}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{el.logLevel}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{el.createdTime}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{el.message}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{el.details}</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
        ) )}
    </TableBody>

    <TableFooter>
        <TableRow>
            <TablePagination component="div" count= {this.props.logs.length}
                rowsPerPage={this.props.rowsPerPage}
                page={this.props.page}
                onChangePage={this.handleNextPageClick}
                onChangeRowsPerPage={this.handleChangeRowsPerPage}
             />
        </TableRow>
    </TableFooter>
</Table>
```

I´ve setted the handleNextPageClick function to execute on onChangePage, this is the function:

```
handleNextPageClick(){
    this.props.dispatch(nextPage(this.props.page))
}
```

Function has already been imported on top also...

This is my action on redux:

```
export function nextPageClick(page){
    type: LOGS_NEXTPAGECLICK_PAGINATION,
    page
}

export function nextPage(currentPage){
    return dispatch => {
        currentPage = currentPage + 1;
        dispatch(nextPageClick(currentPage));
    }
}
```

This is my reducer where I handle the state:

```
export default function logsStore(state = defaultState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case actions.LOGS_NEXTPAGECLICK_PAGINATION:
            return { ...state, page: action.page}
            break;
        default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

Reducer has lots of cases but it would be too much code that doesnt has to do with the problem.

So when I try to select next page button on navigation I get this error:

×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Call API)' of undefined

Comment: Instead of `this.props.dispatch(nextPage(this.props.page))`, have you tried `this.props.nextPage(this.props.page)`?

Comment: Im using connect, it needs to be dispatched...If i do i like you say i get the following error: TypeError: _this.props.nextPage is not a function

Comment: Okay cool. May you please provide the container's code, where you are mapping state and dispatch

Comment: `function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        logs: state.logs.logList,
        loading: state.logs.loading,
        error: state.logs.error,
        errorMsg: state.logs.errorMsg,
        page: state.logs.page,
        rowsPerPage: state.logs.rowsPerPage
    };
} `

Comment: `export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    withStyles(styles, {withTheme: true})
)(Logging);`

Comment: Well, there is no place in this container where you are mapping a function called dispatch, nor is there a place where you are mapping the functions to the view.

Comment: Dispatch() its a method from the redux store...It is by default...Also Im mapping the function on the import on top :
import { nextPage } from '../../redux/actions/logs';

Answer (score 0):

My action on redux didnt had a return lock, now it works:

```
export function nextPageClick(page){
    return
    {
       type: LOGS_NEXTPAGECLICK_PAGINATION,
       page
    };
}
```